# Какой инструмент можно использовать для настройки codestyle для ide для php?

Tags: php, code-style, hint

Есть команда из 5 человек. Нужно сделать так, чтобы мы писали в едином стиле. Какой инструмент для php можно использовать?

Comment: php-codesniffer + `.editorconfig` файл.

Comment: SonarLint для phpstorm (больше для оптимизации, исправлений и т.п. чем для стилистики)

Comment: голову можно применять, казалось бы придерживаться 10 условных правил кодстайла не должно составлять  никаких проблем.

Comment: @teran, В команде есть люди с разным опытом работы. Я уверен, что после месяца работы над проектом, все потихоньку начнут забивать на это. А отдельного человека, который бы всё это менторил у нас выделить не получится.

Comment: @u_mulder, благодарю, это то, что нужно.

Comment: Добавил как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения проблемы следующий:

- в репозиторий проекта добавляется файл `.editorconfig`, который описывает как минимум кодировку файлов проекта, используемые переносы строк, отступы и их размеры (2, 4 и т.д пробелов). Подробнее о формате файла [здесь](https://editorconfig.org/), современные IDE должны его поддерживать, phpStorm так точно поддерживает.
- для анализа и исправления стиля кода можно использовать [php_codesniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer). Там достаточно всяких правил. Прогон кодсниффера можно вешать на какой-нибудь прекоммит-хук или как один из этапов CI\CD.
- третьим шагом можно подключить статический анализатор кода - [phpStan](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/getting-started), [psalm](https://psalm.dev/docs/) или оба (видел и такое).